# After upgrading to Unbound 1.13.0 getting error: udp connect failed: Network is unreachable for port 53

Tags: networking, network-manager

I recently upgraded to Unbound 1.13.0 and when I run:
`sudo systemctl status unbound`
I get the following:

```
● unbound.service - Unbound DNS resolver
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/unbound.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-01-05 13:06:59 AEDT; 1min 54s ago
  Process: 457 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/unbound-anchor -r /etc/unbound/root.hints -a /etc/unbound/root.key (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 484 (unbound)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2063)
   CGroup: /system.slice/unbound.service
           └─484 /usr/sbin/unbound -c /etc/unbound/unbound.conf -d

Jan 05 13:06:59 raspberrypi unbound-anchor[457]: [1609812419] libunbound[457:0] error: udp connect failed: Network is unreachable for 199.7.83.42 port 53
Jan 05 13:06:59 raspberrypi unbound-anchor[457]: [1609812419] libunbound[457:0] error: udp connect failed: Network is unreachable for 2001:500:12::d0d port 53
Jan 05 13:06:59 raspberrypi unbound-anchor[457]: [1609812419] libunbound[457:0] error: udp connect failed: Network is unreachable for 2001:500:2::c port 53
Jan 05 13:06:59 raspberrypi unbound-anchor[457]: [1609812419] libunbound[457:0] error: udp connect failed: Network is unreachable for 2001:dc3::35 port 53
Jan 05 13:06:59 raspberrypi unbound-anchor[457]: [1609812419] libunbound[457:0] error: udp connect failed: Network is unreachable for 202.12.27.33 port 53
Jan 05 13:06:59 raspberrypi unbound-anchor[457]: [1609812419] libunbound[457:0] error: udp connect failed: Network is unreachable for 193.0.14.129 port 53
Jan 05 13:06:59 raspberrypi unbound-anchor[457]: [1609812419] libunbound[457:0] error: udp connect failed: Network is unreachable for 2001:500:200::b port 53
Jan 05 13:06:59 raspberrypi unbound-anchor[457]: [1609812419] libunbound[457:0] error: udp connect failed: Network is unreachable for 2001:500:9f::42 port 53
Jan 05 13:06:59 raspberrypi unbound-anchor[457]: [1609812419] libunbound[457:0] error: udp connect failed: Network is unreachable for 199.9.14.201 port 53
Jan 05 13:06:59 raspberrypi unbound-anchor[457]: [1609812419] libunbound[457:0] error: udp connect failed: Network is unreachable for 2001:500:2d::d port 53
```

This is my [unbound.conf](https://pastebin.com/RbxQi2jg) file which might give a clue to the issue I'm experiencing.

I'm just beginning to learn linux systems so it could be I messed up somehow and I'm not sure how to fix it. Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: It's actually Debian. Apologies for not mentioning it in my OP